# How to translate and edit Excel content in a foreign language?

Tags: microsoft-excel, language

I've got this Excel file in a foreign language. Excel 365 has the option to show the translation in English, but it's unable to apply the translation directly in the file (correct me if wrong). What other options do I have to translate the files content besides manual editing? Is it possible to write a script to automate the process? I have hundreds of similar files, so manual editing can take days if not weeks.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.ca/?tr=f&hl=en) can accept files like Excel or csv now.

However, it won't generate a new file but only show the result in your browser. You will have to import them back.